# 310 redirect .htaccess : everityng after /directory/subdirectory to /directory/subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hello my old site had a lot of links like:
https://www.siteurl.com/portfolio/web-design-portfolio/old-link1
https://www.siteurl.com/portfolio/web-design-portfolio/old-link2
eccc

In my new site I`d like to 301 redirect all the old links after /portfolio/web-design-portfolio/ to https://www.siteurl.com/portfolio/web-design-portfolio/

Can you please help? I tried some tutorial but with not much luck.

Here is my latest try, but I obtain a "too many redirects" error:

```html
# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  
  # /portfolio/web-design-portfolio/any-link to portfolio/web-design-portfolio/
  RewriteRule ^portfolio/web-design-portfolio/(.*)$ /portfolio/web-design-portfolio/ [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[4.0.15]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
# Le direttive (linee) tra `BEGIN WordPress` e `END WordPress` sono
# generate dinamicamente, e dovrebbero essere modificate solo tramite i filtri di WordPress.
# Ogni modifica alle direttive tra questi marcatori verrà sovrascritta.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

# BEGIN ShortPixelWebp
# Le direttive (linee) tra `BEGIN ShortPixelWebp` e `END ShortPixelWebp` sono
# generate dinamicamente, e dovrebbero essere modificate solo tramite i filtri di WordPress.
# Ogni modifica alle direttive tra questi marcatori verrà sovrascritta.

# END ShortPixelWebp
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your htaccess rules file in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this rule at the top of .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  
  # /portfolio/web-design-portfolio/any-link to portfolio/web-design-portfolio/
  RewriteRule ^portfolio/web-design-portfolio/(.*)$ /portfolio/web-design-portfolio/ [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried but  i receive the error " too many redirects" and the page /portfolio/webdesign wont` load.